# Difference in assigned and output value of a double

Tags: c

I'm very new to programming, so, if I have not used the exact terms to express, please excuse..

I tried to output the double value in different values, but when I tried to do the below the value is changed can anyone explain me why is this happening..

In the program;

```
int main()
{
//  double i=555555.555555;             //--------------------------------(A)
//  double i=5555555555555555.555555;   //--------------------------------(B)
//  double i=555555555555555.555555;    //--------------------------------(C)

    printf("%f",i);
    printf("\n%lf",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Output for

```
line (A):
555555.555555
555555.555555

line (B): 
555555555555555.560000
555555555555555.560000

line (C):
5555555555555556.000000
5555555555555556.000000
```

In the above, if I compile with line (A), I will get a proper output.

But, if I try the line (B) and (C), the output varies, and in the line (C) the value id completely changed.

Please help me with this confusion..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Just read this: http://floating-point-gui.de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating-point decimal values generally do not have an exact binary representation. This is a side effect of how the CPU represents floating point data. For this reason, you may experience some loss of precision, and some floating-point operations may produce unexpected results.

This behavior is the result of one of the following:

1. The binary representation of the decimal number may not be exact.
2. There is a type mismatch between the numbers used (for example,
       mixing float and double).

To resolve the behavior, most programmers either ensure that the value is greater or less than what is needed, or they get and use a Binary Coded Decimal (BCD) library that will maintain the precision.
Binary representation of floating-point values affects the precision and accuracy of floating-point calculations.

Taken from: [Why Floating point number loose precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c151dt3s.aspx)

Comment: People do use arbitrary-precision or multi-precision libraries like GMP (https://gmplib.org/), but they don't often use BCD.  Related concepts, but not the same.